# WPF C# - pack window into page

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, window

I'm trying to pack WPF Window into Page class and show it as a part of my application. I really need build in application. Is it possible?

I created Page class MyPage.xaml with MyPage.xaml.cs. 
In contructor of MyPage I have

```
public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _prompt = new MyPrompt();
        _prompt.ReadLine += new ReadLineEventHandler(CommandHandler);
        //_prompt.Show();

        this.Content = _prompt;
    }
```

This of course doesn't work. After uncomment //_promt.Show(); line I have seperated window. Is any possibility to make this a part of page?

Answer (score 0):

> Is any possibility to make this a part of page?

No, it isn't. A `Window` must be the root of the element tree and you cannot add a `Window` as a child of a `Page` or any other visual I am afraid.

What you could do is to move the contents of your window into a `UserControl` and use an instance of this one as the `Content` of your `Page`. But you *cannot* use the window directly.

Comment: @Tatarinho: Please accept the answer and vote it up once your question has been answered.